# Docker - Angular app image is not working ("/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found)

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

So I've got an angular app for which I've created a **Dockerfile** . Tried to created build out of it and after resolving some build issues it was successfull. The container is running but application is not and this is what I see in logs of NgInx

```
2021/11/26 13:13:03 [error] 8#8: *1 "/etc/nginx/html/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:82"
172.17.0.1 - - [26/Nov/2021:13:13:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36 Edg/94.0.992.50"
```

This is my docker file

```
FROM node:12 as build-stage
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine as production-stage
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/java-poc /usr/share/nginx/html
```

This is my build script in package.json file

```
"scripts": {  
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
 },
```

This is my NgInx conf file which I'm trying to override in NGINX image.

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

#log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
#                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
#                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

#access_log  logs/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

server {
    listen       82;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

   location /api/auth-ms {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9092/auth-ms;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    }


    location /api/test-engine  {
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:9092/test-engine;
                    proxy_set_header Host   $host;
                    proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            }
    
    

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#    listen       8000;
#    listen       somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}


# HTTPS server
#
#server {
#    listen       443 ssl;
#    server_name  localhost;

#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
#}

}
```

can some one point to me in some direction what went wrong here?

EDIT: Just checked if index.html is present . That checked out as well
[image]

My conf file is also copied there and I have matched the contents too

Comment: (Compare the error message, your Dockerfile, and the Nginx `root` directive.)

Comment: Thank you so much. I seems I was copying the build files into the wrong directory. It is working now.  The error message even said it all. Thanks for pointing me into right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I was copying build files into wrong directory. It solved now . Just need to change this line of dockerfile

```
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/java-poc /etc/nginx/html
```